# Schur complement and positive semidefinite cones

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite, linear-matrix-inequality, schur-complement

I know that my question might be trivial but I would appreciate your feedback.

I know that the Schur complement can be used to express a quadratic inequality as a positive semidefinite matrix and vice-versa. Why is that true? Is the Schur complement of a PSD matrix an equivalent of it? For example, in the image below

[image]

I know that positive semidefinite matrices, characterized by the non-negativity of their principal minors, i.e., for the linear matrix inequality (LMI)

$$\begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ y & z \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 $$

this yields $x \ge 0$, $z \geq 0$ and $xz−y^2\ge0$.

Is $xz−y^2\ge0$ equivalent to the following LMI?

$$\begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ y & z \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 $$

I'm really confused about the relationship between these inqualities and the LMI and the rule of Schur's complement in this? Please help!

Comment: What exactly is the question? You say you know that PSD-ness of $[x\ y; y\ z]$ is equivalent to $x\geq 0, xz\geq y^2$. That is perfectly true. It is the lowest-dimensional case of Lemma 6.1 here https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/sdo.html#properties-of-semidefinite-matrices

Comment: My question isI have seen lemma 6.1. It gives a condition for the matrix X to be positive (semi) definite using Schur's complement. My question is about whether these two inequalities are equivalent to the original matrix. I'm asking since that I can use these inequalities to convert a SOCP inequality to PSD cone for example. Would this mean that Schur's inequality is an exact representation for the PD (PSD) cone or it is just a condition to prove that the cone is PD or PSD? For example, the graph was drawn based on  $$xz-y^2\ge0$$, would that mean that this inequality is in fact the PSD cone?

Comment: The Schur lemma says the big matrix is PSD if and only if the two smaller matrices are PSD. So in this sense it is any equivalent representation. Yes SOCP is reducible to a semidefinite problem by this kind of reduction. But then SOCPs are more efficiently solved directly than by casting them to SDPs.

Comment: This one inequality plus $x\geq 0$ determines $S^2_+$.

Comment: I understand this point about the SOCP and SDP. my confusion is about the inequality itself, is it equivalent to the original PSD cone and can be used to draw it as in the image? I understood from your last answer that it is. My last question is what is $$S^2_+$$. does it mean a PSD cone of size 2?

Comment: Yes, if you want to visualize the cone of 2x2 symmetric PSD matrices ($S^2_+$)  then those are the inequalities to draw it in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: What does this have to do with the Schur complement?  PSD-ness of a $2 \times 2$ matrix means that the diagonal entries are non-negative and that the determinant is also non-negative.  In total, 3 inequalities.

Comment: My understanding is that Schur complement can be used to convert quadratic inequalities into LMI. Would that mean that Schur complement is an equivalent of the LMI? This is very confusing for me.